# Masking div content using svg image

Tags: css, svg, mask, masking, clipping

Example: `codepen.io/rudza/pen/NMqVEK`

There is a yellow div which will contain some image content.

Also, there is svg speech_bubble.

Would it be possible to mask the svg over the div to show only the content inside? 
And is it possible to keep transparent background?

Comment: I think it would be easier to just play with position relative/absolute and overflow hidden of the `#content` parent

Comment: Do you have a working example? @Fecosos

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using PNG masking: codepen.io/rudza/pen/JvdQYv